# Javascript's prototype, how to inherit a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I need an inheritance relation between two classes in Javascript.
I like to declare properties inside Constructor; for methods, prototype:

```
function Animal(){
   this.someProperty = 'someProperty';
   this.init();
}
Animal.prototype = {
   init : function(){ }
   anotherMethod : function(){ }
}
```

I think declaring methods like that brings more readability than:

```
 Animal.prototype.init = function(){ }
 Animal.prototype.anotherMethod = function(){}
```

But when I need to inherit some class from another, I don't find the way to do it my way. This is not working:

```
  Cat.prototype = new Animal();
  Cat.prototype = {
      init : function(){ }
  }
```

I know that I can do it like next:

```
  Cat.prototype = new Animal();
  Cat.prototype.init = function(){ }
  Cat.prototype.anotherMethod = function(){ }
```

but, is there a way do it my way?

Comment: I think you will love new node.js EC6 class feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

Check out some inheritance approaches to get inheritance working:

- http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html
- http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance

The example from the first link that might sum it up, which is similar but a little different:

```
function Mammal(name){ 
    this.name=name;
    this.offspring=[];
} 
Mammal.prototype.haveABaby=function(){ 
    var newBaby=new Mammal("Baby "+this.name);
    this.offspring.push(newBaby);
    return newBaby;
} 
Mammal.prototype.toString=function(){ 
    return '[Mammal "'+this.name+'"]';
} 


Cat.prototype = new Mammal();        // Here's where the inheritance occurs 
Cat.prototype.constructor=Cat;       // Otherwise instances of Cat would have a constructor of Mammal 
function Cat(name){ 
    this.name=name;
} 
Cat.prototype.toString=function(){ 
    return '[Cat "'+this.name+'"]';
} 


var someAnimal = new Mammal('Mr. Biggles');
var myPet = new Cat('Felix');
alert('someAnimal is '+someAnimal);   // results in 'someAnimal is [Mammal "Mr. Biggles"]' 
alert('myPet is '+myPet);             // results in 'myPet is [Cat "Felix"]' 

myPet.haveABaby();                    // calls a method inherited from Mammal 
alert(myPet.offspring.length);        // shows that the cat has one baby now 
alert(myPet.offspring[0]);
```

There are some frameworks out there that focus on prototypical inheritance that will manage some of the plumbing for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the prototype instead of replacing it if you want to keep a syntax similar to what you currently use.

For example, with lodash you use [`assign`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) like this:

```
_.assign(Cat.prototype, {
   init : function(){ }}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

doing this

```
  Cat.prototype = new Animal();
  Cat.prototype = {
      init : function(){ }
  }
```

you overwrite the first declaration, so it will not going to get the Animal methods.

In javascript, you can do inheritance only using prototype

```
  Cat.prototype = new Animal();
  Cat.prototype.init = function(){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set up inheritance using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Next, if you want to use one *Object* to extend another *Object* you could copy it's property descriptors onto the other using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), e.g.

```
function copyAtoB(A, B) {
    var d = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < d.length; ++i)
        Object.defineProperty(
            B,
            d[i],
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(A, d[i])
        );
    return B;
}


function Animal() {
    this.isAnimal = true;
    // etc
}
Animal.prototype = Object.create(null); // Animal doesn't inherit from anything
copyAtoB({
    foo: function () { console.log('foo'); }
}, Animal.prototype);


function Cat() {
    Animal.call(this); // the Animal constructor helps build cats
    this.isCat = true;
    // etc
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // Cat inherits from Animal
copyAtoB({
    bar: function () { console.log('bar'); }
}, Cat.prototype);
```

Now we have

```
var cat = new Cat();
cat.isCat; // true
cat.isAnimal; // true
cat.foo(); // logs "foo"
cat.bar(); // logs "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extend method.

```
Cat.prototype.extend({
  init : function(){ }
}, new Animal());

function extend(destination, source) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(function (key) {
    if(typeof destination[key] === 'undefined') {
      destination[key] = source[key]    
    }
  }
}
```